# Total Row Disappears from Table Visual when Filter Applied

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table visual in Power BI with a column containing dates. That column is provided by a DAX measure. I want the count of the number of dates in the column to appear in the total row at the bottom of the table. I was able to achieve this (I thought) by using `HASONEVALUE` in the DAX measure. But then, when I filter my table visual based on another column's value (fiscal_year), the count disappears from the total row. Can you see why this might be happening in my DAX below?

```
release_date_planned = 

IF(HASONEVALUE(jira_table[fields_Fix_versions_released]),
    IF(SELECTEDVALUE(jira_table[fields_Fix_versions_released])="False" && SELECTEDVALUE(jira_table[fields_Fix_versions_releaseDate]) <> BLANK(),
        FORMAT(DATEVALUE(SELECTEDVALUE(jira_table[fields_Fix_versions_releaseDate])), "MM/dd/yyyy")),
        CALCULATE(
            DISTINCTCOUNT(jira_table[fields_Fix_versions_releaseDate]),
            jira_table[fields_Fix_versions_released]="False" && jira_table[fields_Fix_versions_releaseDate] <> BLANK()))
```

Here's a look at what I'm seeing in the table visual:

(with no filters applied)

[image]

(filtered for fiscal_year 2023)

[image]

(filtered for fiscal_year 2024)

[image]

As you can see. When I filter for 2024, the count disappears.

In case it helps: jira_table[fields_Fix_versions_released] is date type, and fiscal_year is whole number.

I am only filtering by fiscal_year, using a slicer. I get the same experience if I filter directly using the table visual's filters though.

Comment: Can you share a .pbix?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I cannot share the pbix for this one.